# Minimum distance between a set of points and a specific point

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have cordinates(longitude and lattitude) of set of points making a path and i also have a specific point . I want to find minimum distance between this point and set of points.Please suggest a optimized aproach as i have to make this query very frequently.

Comment: What database?  In Postgres, you should use https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html as an approach.

Comment: I'm using MySQL.And actually i dont want to calculate the distance but i want to know if the point is out of path for example i want to know that if minimum distance of the point from the path is more than 100 meters .

Comment: Specifying the database matters.  Every database has some geometry stuff built in, and using that is better than trying to roll your own.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably recommend using a dynamic convex hull algorithm or something like it. The furthest point in this case is always on the convex hull. Add the point you are tracking to the hull (O(log N)), since you know one point on the hull, in theory you might be able to find the furthest point in O(log h) but at worst it would be O(h) where h is the number of points on the convex hull. In a random point set, h is roughly O(sqrt N), but depends on what your point set looks like.